# Banshee can't find my music after changing HD mount options

Tags: 16.04, music, banshee

So, after spending a few days setting up my music library just the way I wanted it... I made the dumb decision to play around with the auto-mount settings in the disks utility which has broken all the functionality of the music library I built.

Previously, the HD containing all of my music files was in `/media/Cactus/Etc/Music` and because of the new auto-mount instructions, the folder is now in `/mnt/Etc/Music`

This means that the file directories of all ~5500 songs are "missing" according to Banshee.  Is there any easy way to get banshee to recognize that I moved all my music files? In particular, I don't want to have to go through the hassle of rebuilding a ~2100 song playlist 1 song at a time...

Comment: The only easy way is undoing what you did.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured out a solution. I went into the settings of Banshee, selected a new default Music folder at the new mount address and had Banshee import media again.  Everything now points to the right folders, Praise Jeebus!